# session time out after login

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js

i have a vue app and it's work. but then there were some issues where one of a user tell me that he cannot login through his chrome version 79.0.3945.117 while i'm also using that chrome version and working fine without any problem, i ask him to check if there any error showing up in console, other user that using the same kind of browser also work fine.

but there was no error. he just was kick out from the site after he's login. the login actually was sucess but being forced to end session.

can i know if this is caused by the browser or my front end? what is usually the caused of this issues?

Comment: Is he using the incognito mode ? Maybe the session is not saved.

Comment: @AdrianA both incognito and normal window has he used but still cannot working